# tuning ElasticNet parameters sklearn package in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to implement ElasticNet from sklearn package using GridSearchCV.
my data is all numeric!
I got an error and i do not understand what is the problem.
when trying to implement linear regression and lasso it was not a problem.
can someone help?

The code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Use grid search to tune the parameters:

    parametersGrid = {"max_iter": [1, 5, 10],
                      "alpha": [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100],
                      "l1_ratio": np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)}

    eNet = ElasticNet()
    grid = GridSearchCV(eNet, parametersGrid, scoring='accuracy', cv=10)
    grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    Y_pred = grid.predict(X_test)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\..\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 58, in _assert_all_finite
    " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: Are you sure that your data is all numeric and is within range of `float64`? Are you using same `X_train` and `y_train` for Lasso and LinearRegressor?

Comment: scoring='accuracy' is a bit strange for a regression problem. This scoring should be used for classification problems.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar, its the same train and test. the data is numeric. how do i make sure that it is within the range of float64?

Comment: @Miriam Farber you are right! change it to: neg_mean_absolute_error. got the same error.

Comment: Are you not getting any error in Lasso or LinearRegressor? Please post the full stack trace of error along with some data. What does `np.isfinite(X_train).all()` and `np.isfinite(y_train).all()` return?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change accuracy, which is for classification to r2 for regression:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(eNet, parametersGrid, scoring='r2', cv=10)
```

and remove nan etc values from the data

```
indx = ~np.isnan(x).any(axis=1)
X_train = X_train[indx]
Y_train = Y_train[indx]
```

These are two direct issues i see in code & from the error stack